# How to create a custom form

Tags: email, forms

I need to create a custom form inside my site, in particularly inside a CMS page. The form action should send an email with a summary of the data entered.

It would be even better if the data were stored in the database and accessible through the backend but this is not essential.

What is the best way to do this? Should I create a module?

Comment: I don't need to create a new page. The form should be inside an existing cms page.

Comment: The way you use it is not important. You can put your form in a cms page. But you still need a controller to handle the form submission. So it's almost the same thing.